# Spin and Representation Theory

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

So for integer spin, the way I understand it mathematically (in a classical limit), is that under a Lorentz transformation (i.e. change of coordinates), spin $n$ particles transform like rank $n$ covariant tensor fields. This makes wonderful sense to me because the induced representation of $SO^+(1,3)$ on $\bigotimes^n \mathbb R^{1,3}$ is given in coordinates by the same rule.

The situation for spin $1/2$ particles is trickier for me to see. I know that generally spinors are elements in a complex vector space $\Delta$, which admits a faithful representation of of the Clifford algebra $CL(t,s)$, called the Dirac representtion. In case of $t=1,s=3$, we have that $\Delta=\mathbb{C}^4$, and the representation is given by the isomorphism $CL(1,3)\otimes \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \text{End}(\mathbb{C}^4)$. We define the double cover $\text{Spin}^+(1,3)\rightarrow SO^+(1,3)$ as subset of $CL(1,3)$, then the spinor representation is the faithful given by the restriction of this isomorphism to $\text{Spin}^+(1,3)$, which has image in $GL(\mathbb{C}^4)$.

What I don't understand is how to characterize how spin $1/2$ particles transform under a Lorentz transformation. In particular, fermions are spinor fields, i.e. maps $\Psi:\mathbb{R}^{t,s}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{t,s}\times \Delta$ which satisfy:
$$\pi_{\mathbb{R}^{t,s}}\circ \Psi=\text{Id}_{t,s}$$
However, how do we prescribe a representation of $SO^+(1,3)$ on these spinor fields? I know that spinor fields have a natural transformation property related to the spinor representation of the double cover $\text{Spin}^+(1,3)$ on $\mathbb{C}^4$, but how do we translate this into a representation of $SO^+(1,3)$ on $\mathbb{C}^4$ ?

Edit:

Ok I think I get it now, each element in $\text{Spin}^+(t,s)$ maps to an element in $SO^+(1,3)$, so under $\text{Spin}^+(t,s)$, we have that spinor fields then transform under $\text{Spin}^+(t,s)$ by:

$$g\cdot \Psi=g\cdot (x,\psi(x))=(\lambda(g)\cdot x,\kappa(g)\cdot \psi(x))$$

where $\lambda$ is the covering map, and $\kappa$ is the spinor representation. Does that make sense?

Comment: You should look for Wigner Weyl construction of spinors. The core idea is to write t,x,y,z as one matrix using the Pauli matrices, and then do rotations and Lorentz boosts on them. Then that gives two different possible choices for Lorentz boosts, and you can slowly generate all the possible stuff with them

Comment: Why do you need a representation of $\mathrm{SO}^+(1,3)$ instead of $\mathrm{Spin}(1,3)$ on these fields?

Comment: @ACuriousMind because how well can we characterize spin 1/2 particles by how they transform under a change of coordinates?

Comment: @ACuriousMind  is what I've written correct? I am trying to characterize this in a way that is independent of dimension of the space.

Comment: @ACuriousMind actually I disagree with what I have written because it doesn't make a lot of sense mathematically.